# Simplify long path/to/repo.git when cloning with git

Tags: git, bash, debian

The git repositories I have on my server (Debian-based) are stored in `/var/git/repositories`.

So when I want to clone one of my repositories from my server, I have to do:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@server.example.com/var/git/repositories/myrepository.git
```

Nothing suprising here, but what a pain to type!
Instead, I would like to do something like:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@server.example.com/myrepository[.git]
```

(Ideally, the .git would be optional... and even the `ssh://user@` part if possible, although `user@` is already optional)

I am aware that I can edit my local `.gitconfig` with:

```
[url "ssh://user@server.example.com/var/git/"]
    insteadOf = fancyshortcut:
```

and clone using the following:

```
$ git clone fancyshortcut:myrepository.git
```

but I was wondering if there was such solution that would be handled by the server itself.

Any idea?

---

**EDIT**

As an example, Github offers nice URLs as follows:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:mylogin/myrepository.git
```

Does someone have an idea how they could do that? (even if I know that they come with a whole infrastructure behind...)

Comment: if you want to have the "server itself" handle it, you should look into SSHd, because that's the only thing handling URLs in the whole process. Git has no server part and uses other protocols (and their daemons) for transport

Comment: I knew a solution would not come from git but I didn't know where to look for. So thanks, SSHd seems like a good candidate though, would you have any more precise thought about that? If yes, it might be a proper solution for my problem, so make it an answer instead of a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using a symbolic link for

```
/git -> /var/git/repositories
```

But this will only work if you have administrative permissions.

Comment: Yep, I could at least do that, but I would prefer to have something transparent on the FS, more something server managed, like SSHd might do (see @Nevik's comment).